# web.config problems with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, web-config, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have a website located [here](http://pontis.inspecttech.com/).  Any link I create is resulting in a 404 error, so I am assuming this has to do with WordPress Permalinks & the web.config file.  For the meantime, I have changed WordPress' permalinks settings to the default, but I would like to change this back.  I have included the web.config's current setup below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you are changing the permalink to "postname" check whether it creates .htaccess in the root folder where the other website files are located or not. If it is not creating the .htaccess then add a blank file there manually named .htaccess and then change the permalink to default and then to "postname" .

Hope it will work..